# Manage svn copy (tags) of sparse checkout

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a SVN repo containing variuos java web projects that are built and deployed as WAR.

Now i'm asked to maintain the build and deploy of that projects as a single EAR.

```
repo
|
\---> projA
|     |
|     \--->trunk
|     |      |
|     |      \->...<src and config>
|     |
|     \--->branches
|     |
|     \--->tags
|
\---> projB
|     |
|     \--->trunk
|     |      |
|     |      \->...<src and config>
|     |
|     \--->branches
|     |
|     \--->tags
|
\---> projC
|     |
|     \--->trunk
|     |      |
|     |      \->...<src and config>
|     |
|     \--->branches
|     |
|     \--->tags
<...>
|
\--> config/META-INF/application.xml
```

WAR and EARs are built with `gradle`.

I can selectively SVN checkout only needed folders (excluding subprojects branches and tags) but I don't understand how to svn tag my checkout.

Any hints?